# CONCAT not working in mysql update query using case

Tags: mysql

I have to validate three columns of a table and update error_suggestion column in that table according to the conditions they satisfy. I am using case for this. The query works fine when one type of validation fails but it does not work when two types of validation fails. The query is executed but the error_suggestion is not updated according to the conditions. Below is my query.

```
SET @exportof='ExportOf Not Available';
SET @RegDate='Registration Data Not Available';
SET @DOB='Event Date Not Available';
SET @comparedate='Registration Date earlier than Birth Date';

UPDATE Import_Tbl_Error_Log
SET error_suggestion = CASE 
            WHEN (`ExportOf` is null or `ExportOf`='') THEN @exportof
            WHEN (`RegistrationDate` is null or `RegistrationDate`='') THEN @RegDate
            WHEN (`bir_le_dob` is null or `bir_le_dob`='') THEN @DOB 
            WHEN  DATE_FORMAT(DATE(`bir_le_dob`),'%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE(`RegistrationDate`),'%Y-%m-%d') THEN @comparedate 

            WHEN ((`ExportOf` is null or `ExportOf`='') AND (`RegistrationDate` is null or `RegistrationDate`=''))
                THEN Concat(@exportof, ', ', @comparedate) 

            WHEN ((`ExportOf` is null or `ExportOf`='') AND (`bir_le_dob` is null or `bir_le_dob`=''))
                THEN Concat(@exportof, ', ', @DOB) 

            WHEN ((`RegistrationDate` is null or `RegistrationDate`='') AND (`bir_le_dob` is null or `bir_le_dob`=''))
                THEN Concat(@RegDate, ', ', @DOB)  

            WHEN ((`RegistrationDate` is null or `RegistrationDate`='') AND (`bir_le_dob` is null or `bir_le_dob`='') AND (`ExportOf` is null or `ExportOf`=''))
                THEN Concat(@exportof, ', ',@DOB,', ',@RegDate) 

            ELSE 0 
       END;
```

For example if ExportOf is does not have any value then it works fine, the table is updated with @ExportOf but when I check for ExportOf and RegistrationDate (Line 8 of Update query) these does not concat and only @ExportOf is updated in the table. Same thing happens for other conditions also. My MySql version is 5.5.39 (If in case it matters). Please help.

Comment: what is the length of your error_suggestion column?

Comment: @excaliburCayote varchar 500

Comment: case when is like an if-else condition, 
when `esportof` is null it always fall to first condition, no chance on reaching the condition you've pointed out

Comment: @excaliburCayote Is there any other way you can suggest by which I can achieve my task ?

Comment: ahhm rearrange or nest your conditions, in such a way that your requirements will properly implemented

Comment: @excaliburCayote If my first four validations are executing and are updated, then why not last four are executing. You mean that whatever I write after AND condition will not work if the first one is satisfied. And I also want that way by which my requirements will properly implement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80637/discussion-between-mukesh-and-excaliburcayote).